# Magento 2 error when trying to reindex

Tags: magento2, indexing

I am currently running Magento 2.3.2. The process went smoothly but after installing some extensions, it appears that some of the reindex tables have been deleted. This is the message I get when trying to reindex:

```
Design Config Grid indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `design_config_dummy_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Customer Grid indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `customer_dummy_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalog_category_product_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalog_product_category_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Catalog Rule Product indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalogrule_rule_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Product EAV indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalog_product_attribute_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Stock indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `cataloginventory_stock_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Inventory indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `inventory_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:14
Product Price indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalog_product_price_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Table status for `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` is incorrect. Can`t fetch version id.
```

Even after using the reset function then reindexing giving same error.
Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK I think I have the answer here.

The issue is that Magento checks table status and doesn't find the key as an auto_increment value (even though it is.)

If you run this:

```
show table status;
```

And scroll down to your offending table, you may find that the AUTO_INCREMENT value is set to null. That's what Magento means by "Table status incorrect".

My fix was to run this (changing table name for each one obviously):

```
alter table `my_table_cl` auto_increment = 1;
```

Potentially you may also have a caching issue described in the accepted answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705477/mysql-show-table-status-auto-increment-is-not-correct). If my line still doesn't fix the problem try changing that cache setting.

Also if something were to go wrong where the version_id really wasn't auto_increment for some reason, you'll get this error. The solution there would be to just alter the column to make it AUTO_INCREMENT.

Later Edit:
An alternative to turning off the status caching is to run this command after your index update:

```
analyze table `my_table_cl`
```

Which will force a refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Reset all index

```
bin/magento ind:reset
```

and try again.

Comment: I have this issue in 2.3.2 and indexer:reset does not fix the issue.